# How to copy a file on several directories with the name *Co* (where *=wildcard)

Tags: copy, wildcard, directory

How to copy a file to several directories of the form *Co*? or *52?

Apparently, just typing

```
    cp fileA *Co*
```

won't work.

My other concern is that if a directory already contains fileA, I don't want it to be overwritten. That is, if the directory *Co* contains fileA, do NOT copy. Is there a one line solution for this, since I think writing a script with if-else is an overkill.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your version of `cp` supports `-n`, you can do:

```
find . -name '*Co*' -exec cp -n fileA {} \;
```

If not:

```
find . -name '*Co*' -exec sh -c 'test -f $0/fileA || cp fileA $0' {} \;
```

Note that these will each descend recursively: if you don't want that you can limit the scope of find.  To find either *Co* or *52, you can do:

```
find . \( -name '*Co*' -o -name '*52' \) -exec ...
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot! Although what I used is find ./*Co*/ -exec file A {} \;